# How do I run Mono on Windows?

Tags: mono

How can I create applications with Mono on Windows, I installed it, but all there is is a Command Prompt interface. I want to know the location of the IDE, or at least how to install it. Thanks

Comment: http://monodevelop.com/ ?

Comment: Oh, I was looking at www.mono-project.com/‎, no wonder I didn't get what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Xamarin Studios, click start building apps, new, select your programming type, done. Maybe I'm missing something but that seems fairly standard? Good luck!